# Jackson objectMapper to use multiple configurations

Tags: jackson, fasterxml

I'm having 2 classes: Class A which contains Class B. 
I need to unmarshall json to the Class A type - but I need Class A to have one set of Deserialization features and Class B to have a different set.
Is it possible? 
What would be the best way doing that?
Thx!

Comment: If you know specific features you want to differ, it might help to mention those. Jackson has many ways to configure things, and some are more reusable than others.

Comment: I'm trying to differ the unwrap root value feature (one class enabled and the other need to be disabled)

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you want to change `SerializationFeature` or `DeserializationFeature` on per-call basis, you do not want use methods in `ObjectMapper`, but rather construct `ObjectReader` and/or `ObjectWriter` like so:

```
static final ObjectMapper mapper = ...; // only create once, acts as factor
// later on
byte[] json = mapper.writer(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
    .without(SerializationFeature. WRAP_EXCEPTIONS)
    .writeValueAsBytes(value);
MyType result = mapper.readerFor(MyType.class)
    .with(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE)
    // and more 'with' or 'without' calls
    readValue(json);
```

Note that whereas construction of `ObjectMapper` is expensive, and instance absolutely need to be reused, construction of `ObjectReader` and `ObjectWriter` are cheap and are meant to be done on per-read/-write basis. So while they can be reused (instances are fully thread-safe, immutable) there is not necessarily much need.

Comment: Thx @StaxMan - The issue wasn't on per-call basis but on per-type basis (I had class which contained another class and they needed different configurations). I'll write my findings in an answer to this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I solved it by defining my own deserializer for the inner type and inside defining new static ObjectMapper of its own to hold the needed configurations.

```
public ObjectMapper MyObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    objectMapper            
            .setAnnotationIntrospector(new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(TypeFactory.defaultInstance()))           
    SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule("PostSurveyModule", Version.unknownVersion());
    simpleModule.addDeserializer(MyInnerObject.class, new MyInnerObjectDeserializer());
    objectMapper.registerModule(simpleModule);

    return objectMapper;
}

public static class MyInnerObjectDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<MyInnerObject> {
    static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    static {
        objectMapper                
                .setVisibilityChecker(objectMapper.getDeserializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
                .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.PUBLIC_ONLY));

        objectMapper.addMixInAnnotations(MyInnerObject.class, MyInnerObjectMixin.class); //some mixin to add
        
    }   

    @Override
    public MyInnerObject deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        MyInnerObject myInnerObject = objectMapper.readValue(jp, MyInnerObject.class);
        return myInnerObject;
    }
}
```